# asp.net mvc - convert &lt;br&gt; to <br/> in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, itext, editor, telerik-mvc

My application is ASP.NET MVC2 C#, I am using Telerik MVC Editor and itextsharp to produce a PDF file.  My challenge is `<br />` shows in the PDF rather than a new paragraph.

In the editor I have:

```
.Encode(false)
```

In the controller I am using:

```
er.Comments = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(recommendation.Comments);
```

so far everything works well.

To produce my PDF, I am using:

```
BPR = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(this.Recommendations.**Comments**)
List<IElement> htmlarraylist = iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.HTMLWorker.ParseToList(new StringReader(BPR ), null);
```

Comments is stored as in the database as:

```
First Paragraph <br /> Second paragraph
```

However when I debug the program, BPR is converted to:

```
First Paragraph &lt;br /&gt; Second paragraph
```

Is there a way to convert `&lt;br /&gt;` back to `<br/>`?

Comment: Do you get this in outputted pdf or in "watch-like" window?

Comment: Yes I do, it is  First Paragraph <br /> Second paragraph

Comment: Do you get "&lt;br /&gt;" in pdf or on watch window? I'm asking because it's ok for some "watch-like" windows to encode it's content.

Comment: Not in the PDF, I see it on debug, checking the value of the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was in this line:

```
BPR = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(this.Recommendations.Comments)
```

Since I getting the values from a database some of the data were already encoded.